# How to combine text in print

Tags: python

I'm trying to print everything my variable contains together, but instead of this

```
-1.5, -2.0
```

I get

```
('-', '1.5', '-', '2.0')
```

My code is

```
import re
numbers = "Number is -1.75"
textnumber = re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', numbers)[0]
number = float(textnumber)
number1 = '-', str(number - 0.25), '-', str(number + 0.25)
print(number1)
```

How can I combine them so output looks like

```
-1.5, -2.0
```

Comment: use `re.search` for a single match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use commas `,`, you create a `tuple` (what is being printed between parenthesis). To perform string concatenation, you need to use `+`

```py
number1 = '-' + str(number - 0.25) + ', -' + str(number + 0.25)
```

Note that you can use f-strings for that purpose, like so:

```py
number1 = f"-{number - 0.25}, -{number + 0.25}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should embed your negative sign inside the regex, as an optional sign (hence invert the position of -0.25 and 0.25). Then avoid crafting strings of numbers, and use them in the `print` directly.

```
import re

numbers = "Number is -1.75"
textnumber = re.search(r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?', numbers)[0]
number = float(textnumber)

print(f'{number + 0.25}, {number - 0.25}')
```

Output:

```
-1.5, -2.0
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.online-python.com/LTGrlgXAiU).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regular expression that can handle (optional) +- signs

For example:

```
from re import compile

p = compile(r'[-+]?(?:\d*\.*\d+)')
numbers = 'Number is -1.75'

if s := p.search(numbers):
    n = float(s[0])
    print(n + 0.25, n - 0.25, sep=', ')
else:
    print('No matching number')
```

**Output:**

```
-1.5, -2.0
```